# Can't run Jupyter Notebook with python 3.9 env

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm new to using python and conda (and linux for that matter) and I've had some trouble running a Jupyter notebook through a python 3.9 environment. I've noticed that the base 3.8.5 environment works (and allows me to open Jupyter 6.1.4) , but I'm not sure why. I've updated anaconda and conda through `conda update conda` and `conda update anaconda` and get the same

```
# All requested packages already installed.
```

In the anaconda-navigator GUI, when I try to use a py39 environment and click install on Jupyter, I notice it tries to install Jupyter version 6.0.3 and I also get [this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxIJe.png)

I've also tried to install pykernel into my env (not sure if it would've done anything to help my issue)  in which I get:

```
$conda install ipykernel
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                      

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

`Specifications:

  - ipykernel -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.9


     Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
    This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
    failed                                                                                                                                    
    
    UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
    to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:
    
    Specifications:
    
      - ipykernel -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
    
    Your python: python=3.9
```

I'm assuming that is why Jupyter was unable to install notebook. I'm really new to this stuff so if any more detail is required from me, please let me know. I don't really understand this issue and can't find anything similar.

Comment: For me it’s quite clearly stated that your Python version (3.9) is incompatible. Also 3.8 is incompatile if you read carefully the error message.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg 3.8 is not incompatible, actually, if you read the error message even more carefully. The last two entries are out of order.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected. While suggesting 'read carefully' one should follow his own advice :-). So it is 3.8 <= compatible <3.8.0a0

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the steps below:

1. `conda create -n py39 python=3.9`
2. `pip3 install --upgrade pip`
3. `pip3 install jupyter`
4. Go to anaconda prompt
5. Activate py39
6. Run jupyter-notebook
7. Run after changing path as per your machine : `python C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install`
8. Run : jupyter-notebook from anaconda prompt
9. Check version of Python on Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Not working for me, also your answer is for windows, OP asked for Linux.

Answer (score -2):

Yo must write three code in the terminal.

1. conda create -n py39 python=3.9
2. pip3 install --upgrade pip
3. pip3 install jupyter